# Conflict between datalist elements in two instances of the same Angular component

Tags: angular

I just finished a form control component which autocompletes the user's input via Google Maps Places Autocomplete JS API. It works perfectly, until I try to use two of them in the same form. In this case only the first one works, the second one is not doing anything. There are no error messages, it just doesn't work.

I believe it's more a general programming practice which I seemingly failed to follow than an actual bug, but it's odd because as far as I know each component has its own scope and can't conflict each other. So, is there any special rule about creating components in order to avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

OK, here is what happened. There is nothing wrong with my component, and I haven't broken any unwritten rule. However there is a possible bug in Angular's DOM handling.

My component uses a text input to enter the city name. The text input has a `list` property pointing to a `datalist` which is populated by Google Maps API. (Although it's possible to directly link the API to the DOM element and let the API handle it, I decided to make it more "Angularish" and put the API call into a service, populating the `datalist` by an array containing the API's answer.)

It is the `datalist` that caused the problem. The HTML5 `datalist` element must have an `id` property which links it to the `input` field via its `list` property. The problem is that if you use two or more instances of the same form element component, somehow the datalist `id` properties confuse Angular. You'll end up with two elements with the same `id` property and therefore your code will not work.

The solution is to generate a random string and pass it both to the datalist's `id` property and the input's `list` property. Here it is:

```
<input type="text" formControlName="location" [attr.list]="randomName">
<datalist [id]="randomName">
  <option *ngFor="let option of optionList">{{ option }}</option>
</datalist>
```

This may be a bug in Angular. The DOM element property is not limited to the component's own scope.